# Original attribute in Fiji / Weka generated arff file

Tags: java, image-processing, machine-learning, classification, weka

I am currently using **Fiji's trainable weka segmentation** to classify diseased and non diseased portions. The classifier works fine, I have include no additional settings in the Training Features, which is stripped to its bare minimum but while examining the data file which I saved after running the classifier, I cannot understand one of the attributes which is present.

```
@relation segment

@attribute original numeric
@attribute Hue numeric
@attribute Saturation numeric
@attribute Brightness numeric
@attribute class {'class 1','class 2'}

@data
81.666664,56,228,136,'class 1'
87.666664,56,219,142,'class 1'
.....
```

What is the **@attribute original** present in the ARFF file? I want to provide input to the classifier through my Java program and I have the values of Hue, Saturation and Value for the pixels but I do not understand what to pass for the original attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, this ARFF file contains fives colums:

- Four columns containing numerical values (original, Hue, Saturation and Brightness)
- One nominal column "class" that contains only two different values "class 1" and "class 2".

There is no way to say from this example what is the column "original". You have to look into the FiJi code to understand.

Comment: Yes, I've tried all possible combinations of classifiers with every different setting but the original attribute always turns up. So I'm confused.

Comment: I'm try that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As @FireTiTi said, the answer is in the [code](https://github.com/fiji/Trainable_Segmentation/blob/master/src/main/java/trainableSegmentation/FeatureStack.java#L237-L241). Your training image is RGB, so the default features are 4:

- "Original" pixel value, [averaging the color intensities](https://github.com/fiji/Trainable_Segmentation/blob/master/src/main/java/trainableSegmentation/FeatureStack.java#L3171): (r + g + b)/3.0.
- "Hue" value (H).
- "Saturation" value (S).
- "Brightness" value (B).

The HSB values are obtained using the standard conversion [implemented in ImageJ](https://github.com/fiji/Trainable_Segmentation/blob/master/src/main/java/trainableSegmentation/FeatureStack.java#L2713-L2720).